# How to tell if nodes are deleted in bash?

Tags: bash, kubectl

```
    while true; do
     kubectl get nodes -o wide
     if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
       echo "Nodegroup deleted successfully"
       break
     fi
     done
```

Before this loop I'm running a delete nodegroup command, it takes some while to delete. How can I break from the loop after the kubectl command returns "No resources found"?

Comment: What is the exit code if no nodes are found? If it's no-zero, add an `else` clause.  Otherwise you could capture the output of the kubectl command and grep for that message.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can try getting the number of nodes available and store it in a variable. Now since we have the count decrement it after each node deletion and in while condition you can check count != 0.

```
while [[count != 0]]; do
     Command for deleting node
     ((count --))
done
```

Comment: @deagleshot is your issue resolved revert back if you are still facing the issue